# CLT of RVS with bounded 3rd moment:

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of independent real RVs with mean $0$ and variance $1$.
We also assume there exists $0<C$ such that $\mathbb E(X_n^3)<C$.
I want to prove C.L.T.

all $X_n$ are in $\mathcal L^3(\Omega)$ so I already proved that:

$\mathbb E(Z_n=(1/\sqrt(n)\sum_{k\leq n}X_n)=0 $ and $var(Z_n)=1$ from the 1st and 2nd moments.

I can also prove that $\mathbb E(Z_n^3)\rightarrow 0$.

How do I go on?

Comment: anyone anything?  been 5 days with no attempt...

Comment: Are you sure the assumption is not $\mathbb E|X_n^3|\lt C$? In this case, you can use Lyapunov's condition.